# updating a table with conditional check

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a website for book rental system. Here I do the work of librarian where inserting the book details are done. So here i want to update the availability of the book if the name of the book is already inserted. My query goes like this. And whenever I try to update the availability of the book the  value again gets inserted.

```
$name=$_POST['bname'];
$avail=$_POST['avail'];
$q=mysql_query("select * from table where name='$name'");
if($name==$q){
  $n=("update table where name='$name' set avail='$avail'+1")
}
```

Comment: why are you still using mysql extension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be,

```
UPDATE table 
SET `avail`= `avail` + 1
WHERE name = '$name'
```

**Warning:** [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 1):

Your update query is wrong . Use this

```
"update table set avail = avail+1 where name = '$name'";
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the first query must be change like this:

```
'SELECT name FROM table WHERE name='.$name
```

and second one:

```
'UPDATE table SET avail = avail+1 WHERE name ='.$name
```